# Batch prediction on TFHub YAMNET model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use a pretrained model to extract embeddings.

Single observation

```
X = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(10, 1000)) # 10 samples of length 1000
yamnet_model_handle = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/yamnet/1'
yamnet_model = hub.load(yamnet_model_handle)

yamnet_model(X[0]) # Works, outputs (scores, embeddings, spectrogram)
```

Multiple observations does not work

```
yamnet_model(X) # Doesn't work
hub.KerasLayer(yamnet_model_handle, 
               trainable=False,)(X) #Doesn't work either
```

How can I get the output for all observations in X?